# Samsung-laptop kernel module

Tags: kernel, samsung

Is `samsung-laptop` kernel module still blacklisted while using UEFI on a Samsung computer? Is there a way to load it without bricking my laptop?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the module is still blacklisted. From the [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-cdimage/+bug/1040557):

> As far as this bug is concerned, the installation
>   procedure is to update your firmware to the newest version and then install
>   Ubuntu as usual.
>
> Driver support for particular laptop models should probably be addressed in
>   separate bug reports.

So the module is still blacklisted with UEFI.

> No. Despite not directly causing the bricking, the `samsung-laptop` driver
>   will only work in CMS mode and will cause random and potentially very bad
>   problems when running under UEFI. The driver support issue is separate from
>   this bug.

Comment: +1, Reading through that bug report. A Samsung laptops bricking party,  this bug had very high impact. Something I shouldn't try.